# Unwarping a texture in OpenGL

Tags: math, opengl, transformation, vertex-shader

Say I've got a texture mapped to a grid screen-aligned mesh. It looks something like:

[image: original image]

The vertex positions are:

```
(-1, -1), (1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, 1)
```

The UVs:

```
(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1,1)
```

I warp the image by moving around the vertices and save the output by doing a `glReadPixels()`.

The new warped vertex positions are:

```
(-1, -1), (0.8, -0.8), (-0.6, 0.6), (0.4, 0.4)
```

And the produced output is like:

[image: warped image]

Next time as an input I use the *warped image* that I've just saved. What I'm trying to do is reverse the warping effect I did before, by modifying the vertex coordinates. Initially I thought that the coordinates that would unwarp the image must be something of the sort:

```
x_unwarp = 2 * x_original - x_warped
```

But it's not working. The warping effect doesn't get undone. What I get is something like:

[image: attempted unwarp]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how is should modify the vertex coords or perhaps uvs? I'm sure I've got the math wrong.

Thanks!

### UPDATE

It seems that my formula is wrong. I should've used matrices:

```
transform_matrix * x_original = x_warped
```

and then:

```
x_unwarped = inverse(tranform_matrix) * x_original
```

As the transformation I'm doing is pure scaling, the transform matrix is like:

```
/     \
| S  0 |
| 0  S |
\      /
```

Where S is the scale factor. Therefore the inverse would be:

```
/         \
| 1/S  0  |
| 0   1/S |
\         /
```

Thus this would give the unwarping vertex positions as:

```
(-1, -1), (1.25, -1.25), (-1.67, 1.67), (2.5, 2.5)
```

Seems straighter, but still incorrect:

[image: second attempt to unwarp]

### Second update

I seem to have started it wrong from the beginning. There's been some random factor in all the renders. I'm going to fix that and try it again.

### Update: UV warp

Done it using UV warping this time.

Warped using these UVs:

```
(0.0, 0.0), (0.9, 0.0), (0.0, 0.8), (0.7, 0.7)
```

This produced:

[image: uv warped]

And then tried to unwarp using the inverses:

```
(0.0, 0.0), (1/0.9, 0.0), (0.0, 1/0.8), (1/0.7, 1/0.7)
```

Which looks like:

[image: unsuccessful uv unwarp]

This didn't do it either. I'm starting to worry about the 1/0 cases that I just overlook.

Completely clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you're running into is perspective incorrect texture mapping (you can see in the first picture, that the texture coordinates are interpolated differently for each of the two triangles a quad is made of). You can either use perspective correction on a large single quad (using a fragment shader and implementing the algorithm there), or subdivide your quad into smaller patches.

Now reversing the texture warping is straightforward if you think about it like that: The distortion coordinated of your first step become the UV coordinates for the second step. Of course this requires to understand the distortion vertex positions in a certain range. Recall the OpenGL transformation pipeline:

Modelview → Projection → Clipping → Normalized Device Coordinates. Screen space is the last step, with the viewport dimensions applied. NDC coordinates are in the range [-1,1], but getting to the [0,1] range is easy enough: (x+1)/2

So what you do is performing the transformation pipeline (you can omit the clipping, but you must apply the perspective divide), this gives you the UV coordinates for de-distortion.

Comment: Thanks datenwolf! I can confirm that it indeed works. You're giving exhaustive answers as ever. :-) Sorry to have bothered you with something that simple, but sometimes the simplest things escape me. As to perspective incorrect mapping I don't really understand what you mean. The general idea is that I'll have a mesh grid that will consist of say a dozen rows and a dozen columns, thus there would be a bit more geometry there. Still, could you explain a bit more about how perspective incorrect texture mapping might affect my case? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore: First, read the topic on Perspective Correct Texture mapping on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping#Perspective_correctness – the problem you will encounter eventually is, that the de-distorting triangle seam, projected into texture space, will not coincide with the distortion triangle seam in the texture itself. If both texture mappings are perspective correct, then this problem vanishes.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore: Just for clarification: This not coinciding of the seam will happen, if the triangles the quad it split into don't match. If the topology of distorter and dedistorter are the same, things will cancel out nicely.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well, the mesh used for the distortion and unwarping is the same so there's not going to be a problem according to what you said, right? Still, thanks for mentioning the possible issue. I very highly appreciate your help, datenwolf.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly (which isn't certain, given that my answer feels way too simple :p), why not simply modify your texture by applying a texture matrix (i.e. transform the UVs with a translation, rotation, shearing, etc. matrix as needed) instead of moving the quad it is applied to ?

This would make reversing the transformation a simple matter of inverting your original transformation matrix.

Comment: Do you think there's much difference between moving the uvs rather than the positions?